# error: relation "my_table" does not exist, but actually it exists

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to code a simple nodejs script which access a postgresql database and executes a query.
But when I run the script this appears:

[image]

When I run the query directly from the terminal, it works:

[image]

I can't figure out what is happening. Could someone help me?

Full script:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

let connectionURL = 'postgresql://ezert:<MY PASSWORD>@localhost:5432/mydb';

const client = new Client({
    connectionURL: connectionURL
});

client.connect();

client.query("SELECT * FROM my_table", function (err, result) {

    if (err) {

        console.log('[ERROR]:\n' + err);
        return;

    }

    console.log('[RESULT]:');
    console.log(result.rows);
    return;

});
```

Comment: According to the [docs](https://node-postgres.com/api/client#constructor) it should be `connectionString` instead of `connectionURL`

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my code and now it is working:
Instead of using an url to connect to postgres, I'm using an object:

```
const client = new Client({
    user: 'ezert',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'mydb',
    password: '<MY PASSWORD>',
    port: 5432
});
```

For some reason now it is working...
If someone knows why, please tell me!

Comment: If connectionURL was being silently ignored, then you were connecting to a different database.  Probably a database named 'ezert' rather than one named 'mydb'.  That database didn't have the table created in it.